# Writing a polynomial as a product of two other polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Ok, I have no idea how to do this, or really what even its asking. The original question wasn't in English, so I apologize if the vernacular is off.

We have a polynomial $P(X) = X^4 - 3X^2 - 4$ (of $\mathbb R[X]$). I need to write $P(X)$ as a product of two polynomials of degree 1 and a polynomial of degree 2 with a negative discriminant.

It also gives me a hint: To search for the roots, we can use $Z = X^2$ for the time being.

I wish I could say more, and give you the way that I *attempted* solved this, but I legitimately have no idea what to do here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $X^2=y$, so that our polynomial is $y^2-3y-4$. We are used to factoring quadratics, so we see that $y^2-3y-4=(y-4)(y+1)=(X^2-4)(X^2+1)$.

Now $(x^2-4)=(X-2)(X+2)$ and $(X^2+1)$ has negative discriminant.

The only tricks here are to recognize that you can factor the quartic as if it were a quadratic, and then also recognize the difference of squares $X^2-2^2=(X-2)(X+2)$.

Comment: Holy smokes I'm dense. That should have been obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a quadratic-in-drag.  Notice that
$$x^4 - 3x^2 - 4 = (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 1). $$

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to substitute $X^2 = Z$ is a good start. Now try to solve the equation 
$$X^4 - 3 X^2 -4 = 0$$
$$Z^2 - 3Z - 4 =0$$
$$(Z-4)(Z+1) = 0$$

And then fill in $X^2 = Z$ and factor everything further. Do you think you can take if from here?

Comment: Yep, I've got it. I just read the question, and read the hint, and got scared. I'm assuming that they're telling me to substitute $X^2$ for Z so that I see that it's factorizable more easily. Quick followup question, though. Why did you make it all equal to 0? Thanks.

Comment: Since you want to factor it, an easy way is to find the roots (where your function is 0). For every factor $(x-a)$, a is a root. It is not necessary to do.